# How to Stop Rotating Gallery On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am having trouble modifying this widget to stop rotating once clicked. Does anyone have any idea how to add this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

- Mike

Here is the link to the widget:

http://stromasys.29kdev.com/jcoverflip/

Here is the Javascript:

```
    <script>

    jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
        jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip({
          current: 2,


          beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 210 - 110*offset -10*offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(20,100-20*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
            ];
          },
          afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + 110 + 110*offset + 10*offset)+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(20,100-20*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
            ];
          },
          currentCss: function( el, container ){
        jQuery('#flip>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        el.addClass('selected');
            return [
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 75 )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
              $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: '150px' }, { } )
            ];
          },
          change: function(event, ui){
            jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', ui.to*25);
          }
        });

        jQuery('#scrollbar').slider({
          value: 50,
          stop: function(event, ui) {
            if(event.originalEvent) {
              var newVal = Math.round(ui.value/25);
              jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip( 'current', newVal );
              jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', newVal*25);
            }
          }
        });
      });

var timer=setInterval(next,5000);

function next(){
    var $next=$('#flip>li.selected').next('li');
    if(!$next.length){$next=$('#flip>li:first-child');}
    $next.click();
}

    </script>
```

Comment: @Oriol are you familiar with how to add this functionality? I ask because you were able to help me out with this same widget not too long ago. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions. 

Thanks.

- Mike

Answer (score 0):

Just attach the event handler to any DOM Element:

```
$("a.stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    return false;
});
```

And the **HTML** for the same is:

```
<a href="#" class="stop">Stop</a>
```

If you wanna attach to the image, then this is the code:

```
$(".ui-jcoverflip--item img").click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, 
So how would I attach the event handler to the DOM Element in the code listed above?

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work. Am i doing adding the code in right?

http://stromasys.29kdev.com/jcoverflip/index01.html